# Spring Boot Actuator doesn't read git.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have a simple project with Spring Actuator, also i have a maven plugin generating git.properties (resides in classes directory).

However when i run my app, /actuator/info request shows:

```
{
"git": {}
}
```

Documentation says autoconfigure should pick up properties automatically https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-application-info-git

Comment: Does your jar contain /BOOT-INF/classes/git.properties? If yes, try to set `management.info.git.mode = full`

Comment: i've tried with management.info.git.mode = full  and without.

Comment: ok, found problem,  git.properties 'looked' like properties file, but had {} (json format).
after changing formatting (in plugin conf) it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My mistake,  git.properties was not a 'properties' file in fact.
I didn't see {} around a file content.

after changing configuration/format to properties in git-commit-id-plugin plugin, it works
(plugin was generating git info in json)